# Using Semaphores in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, pthreads, semaphore

I'm trying to use semaphores in Visual Studio for a project.

However, I I get error C1083: Cannnot open include file: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory

Is there a way I can download semaphores?

I've also tried including the pthread directory and I get the same error

Comment: Visual Studio is not POSIX compliant, POSIX being the standard that defines pthreads. You'll need a different toolkit for this or write a porting layer.

Comment: Would using Windows [semaphores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129(v=vs.85).aspx) be an option here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to compile *nix code on windows. This is not impossible, but Visual Studio won't be much help.

pthreads come from the POSIX standard, and Windows does not support POSIX particularly well. Some efforts have been made to port POSIX to windows, Cygwin probably being the most successful, and others have tried to implement what they can in add-on libraries for the GCC family of compilers.

Visual studio primary supports the Microsoft way of doing things. Makes sense, that's their bread and butter. POSIX support is minimal. Someone may have ported pthreads to Visual Studio, but I cannot recommend any.

So, you can either port the pthread-using program or library to use the Win32 equivalents or select a different compiler toolkit that wraps pthreads. This may or may not be trivial without looking at the code you need ported.

[MinGW will probably compile the program or library](http://www.mingw.org/), but I can't guarantee this. The Unix and Windows worlds are just too different for guarantees. You would also have to discard Visual Studio as an IDE.